# How to generate logn instances of 1 out of 2 OT from a single instance of 1 out of n OT?

Tags: oblivious-transfer

I'm reading the paper [Improved OT extension](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/491.pdf). The author said that in semi-honest model, a single instance of $1$ out of n OT may be used to generate $\log n$ instances of $1$ out of $2$ OT. More precisely, the cost of $\text{OT}_{l}^m$ is exactly equal to the cost of $1$ out of n $\text{OT}_{l\log n}^{m/\log n}$.

I wonder why it is so. Are there any references about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate $\log n$ instances of 1-of-2 OT using one $1-of-n$ OT by doing the following.

Let's fix some notation. Let $x$ be the selection index for the receiver and $r_1, \dots, r_n$ be the input from the sender, so at the end of the protocol the receiver gets $r_x$. Note that $x$ has $\log n$ bits.

Additionally, let the input for the $\log n$ 1-of-2 OT be $b_1, \dots, b_{\log n}$ for the receiver and $(m_0^1, m_1^1), \dots, (m_0^{\log n}, m_1^{\log n})$ for the sender.

Now receiver just encode the $\log n$ selection bits $b_i$ into $x$. And sender encodes, for all $i \in [n]$, $r_i = (m_{bit(1,i)}^1 || \dots || m_{bit(\log n,i)}^{\log n}) $ where $bit(j,i)$ is the $j$th bit of the bit-decomposition of $i$.

Answer (score 0):

It’s simplest to understand in the case $n=2^\ell$. Suppose we have $\ell$ instances where there are two choices of message of length $m/\ell$. We write $M_{e,i}$ for the $e$th choice of message for the $i$th instance ($e=0,1$ and $i=0,\ldots, \ell-1$).

We now form $n$ messages by concatenating $\ell$ of these messages. If the bit representation of $j$ is $b_{\ell-1}\cdots b_1b_0$ then the $j$th of our $n$ new messages is $M_{b_\ell-1,\ell-1}|\cdots|M_{b_1,1}|M_{b_0,0}$. Note that these new messages are of length $m$. To request one each of the $\ell$ original 1 out of 2 OT instances, a requester concatenates the $\ell$ choices of bits for a number $j$ in the interval $[0,n)$ and uses the 1 out of $n$ OT mechanism to retrieve the $j$th of our new messages, which is the concatenation of the required $\ell$ messages.